# A question about signed measure?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have question about the definition of sigma-additive of signed measure.

That is:
$\nu(\bigcup E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \nu(E_i)$.

If $\nu(\bigcup E_i)$ is finite,the right-hand side must be absolutely convergence,since if it's not,we can use Riemann Rearrangement Theorem
 to prove it can converge to any real number.

What I don't understand is why it's not necessary to absolutely converge if $\nu(\bigcup E_i) = \infty$

It's easy to list some examples,I need to understand this question. What is the difference if left-hand side is finite and left-hand side is infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu(\bigcup E_i) = +\infty$ then a fortiori $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \nu(E_i) = +\infty$ and so, in particular, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\nu(E_i)| = +\infty$.

If you chose $-\infty$ instead, you can repeat the same argument with a minus sign in front of the series.

Comment: Oh, thanks, (it's a silly question) I don't need to understand it.